# GreenDAO does not update the entity's children tree after insert child entity

Tags: android, orm, refresh, updates, greendao

I have two GreenDAO entity, "Card" have n-1 relation with "Lesson".

```
public class Card {

    private Long id;
    private String SourceText;
    private String TargetText;
    private byte[] Image;
    private Long Point;
    private Long lessonID;
}

public class Lesson {

    private Long id;
    private String LessonName;
    private String ShortDes;
    private String LongDes;
    private byte[] Picture;
    private java.util.Date CreatedDate;
    private String CreatedBy;
    private Long sourceLangID;
    private Long targetLangID;

    /** Used to resolve relations */
    private transient DaoSession daoSession;

    /** Used for active entity operations. */
    private transient LessonDao myDao;


    private List<Card> cards;
}
```

In activity A1 - viewing a lesson L1, I used startActivityForResult(A2), go to A2, and insert some cards to L1's cards list. The record is inserted to DB, but when I finish() in A2 and back to A1, in the onResult event:

```
void loadCards() {
        daoSession = null;
        daoSession = ((FlashcardApplication) getApplicationContext()).daoSession;
        lessonDao = daoSession.getLessonDao();
        currentLesson = null;
        currentLesson = lessonDao.loadByRowId(id);
        cards = currentLesson.getCards();
        lblLessonName.setText("Cards of "+currentLesson.getLessonName());
         daoSession = ((FlashcardApplication) getApplicationContext()).daoSession;
       // cards = cardDao.queryDeep("lessonID = " + currentLesson.getId(), null);
        CardListAdapter adapter = new CardListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lv_item_card_of_lesson, cards);
        lvCards.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 1){
            if(resultCode == CardCreateActivity.SUCCESS){
                loadCards();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This set have " + cards.size() +" cards",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unknowed intent when back to LocalLessonCardManage",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

The cards list is not updated. It still be the same like before inserting. When I relaunch and visit activity A1, the new records displayed. I think GreenDAO is keeping the state of the lesson object `L1`. I know `lessonDao.refresh(l1)` is update only `L1` but not its children tree. Is there a way to refresh the cards list? I want to keep using `startActivityForResult()`, may a dirty-way `startActivity()` to go from `A2` to `A1` will work but I don't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance reasons, the relations are cached and must be updated manually when a modification is made.

Try with this

```
currentLesson.resetCards();
cards = currentLesson.getCards();
```

[Here](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/#Resolving_and_Updating_To-Many_Relations) you have more info about this

Comment: Also, cards = cardDao.queryCardByLessonID(longID) is working too :)